# Weird pixel errors in the corners of my screen

Tags: 14.04, nvidia

In the all the far corners of my screen, I am seeing weird, glitchy dots/errors, in squares of about 2x2 pixels. I am on the most recent version of elementary OS with an nvidia GeForce 9300m and the proprietary nvidia driver version 340.76 (which is the last one supporting my graphics card). I need to keep the proprietary driver for opencl support.

How can I fix these dots? See these screenshots:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appearently this is an issue with my graphics card and the slightly rounded corners of the elementary interface. There is a bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1437468
And a workaround has been proposed here:
http://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/3aj5hi/there_will_be_4_white_dots_at_corner_after_i_wake/
This won't fix the glitch, but it will disable the rounded corners.

Instructions:

> It's not releated to hot corners. It is a problem with your graphic
>   card and the rounded corner mask. You can disable it with d-conf in
>   "org.pantheon.desktop.gala.mask-corners"

I used dconf-editor for this.

Comment: This indeed works, Yet to see if this stays fixed. Will report back soon

Comment: Works but does not stay fixed. This need to be run every time I resume.

Answer (score 0):

If you run following command, white squares will go away.

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.mask-corners enable true
```

I made a custom shortcut to run this command.

[image]

Comment: This looks like a more practical solution to this problem