# Display glitch in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: nvidia, graphics, visual-artifacts

[image]

I am using ubuntu 14.04 lts. Since last week I have been noticing this weird display glitch as in the image above whenever I hover or click over an icon. What can I do to fix this?

I looked up some questions like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/469701/weird-partial-screen-flickering-after-upgrade-to-14-04) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/647153/weird-pixel-errors-in-the-corners-of-my-screen), and I checked if there's some issue with my graphics card but it seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a NVIDIA card? I heard the proprietary driver has a bug, and I had the same problem as you. You could try this:

In the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
```

Then reboot, and open Software & Updates. Under Additional Drivers you will now find several NVIDIA drivers, some marked open source. Choose one of them and click on Apply Changes. Then Close and reboot. That solved it for me.